# Reiniciar conteo regresivo cada cierto tiempo

Tags: javascript, html

```
var target_date = new Date('March, 4, 2019').getTime();


var days, hours, minutes, seconds;


var countdown = document.getElementById('countdown');


setInterval(function() {


    var current_date = new Date().getTime();
    var seconds_left = (target_date - current_date) / 1000;


    days = parseInt(seconds_left / 86400);
    seconds_left = seconds_left % 86400;

    hours = parseInt(seconds_left / 3600);
    seconds_left = seconds_left % 3600;

    minutes = parseInt(seconds_left / 60);
    seconds = parseInt(seconds_left % 60);


    countdown.innerHTML = '<span class="days">' + days + ' <label>Dias</label></span> <span class="hours">' + hours + ' <label>Horas</label></span> <span class="minutes">' +
        minutes + ' <label>Min</label></span> <span class="seconds">' + seconds + ' <label>Seg</label></span>';

}, 1000);
```

tengo este conteo regresivo, pero me gustaría que cada 30 minutos se reinicie solo, pero no se como hacer.
porque así como esta cuando llega a 0 empieza a avanzar en valores negativos.

agradezco la ayuda

Comment: Te falta añadir una sentencia `if` que cuando llegue a 0 se ejecute la función `clearinterval`, te dejo aquí un ejemplo completo y funcional https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_countdown.asp

Answer (score 1):

No consigo entender para que lo quieres reiniciar cada 30 minutos, pero aquí esta la solución para que no te continúe cuando se llegue a 0. Utiliza `clearInterval()`, lo que hace es parar el `interval` que definiste.

```js
//metemos el interval en una variable para poder pararlo despues
function timer(){
  var current_date = new Date().getTime();
  var seconds_left = (target_date - current_date) / 1000;
  days = parseInt(seconds_left / 86400);
  seconds_left = seconds_left % 86400;
  hours = parseInt(seconds_left / 3600);
  seconds_left = seconds_left % 3600;
  minutes = parseInt(seconds_left / 60);
  seconds = parseInt(seconds_left % 60);
  countdown.innerHTML = '<span class="days">' + days + ' <label>Dias</label></span> <span class="hours">' +
      hours + ' <label>Horas</label></span> <span class="minutes">' + minutes + 
      ' <label>Min</label></span> <span class="seconds">' + seconds + ' <label>Seg</label></span>';

  //Cuando se termine la cuenta atras
  if(days == 0 && hours == 0 && minutes == 0 && seconds == 0){
      clearInterval(tiempoAtras);
      //aqui pones la fecha nueva, para que te sume los 30 minutos
      target_date = new Date('March, 4, 2019').getTime();
      // y ejecutas el interval otra vez
      tiempoAtras = setInterval(timer, 1000);
  }
}
var tiempoAtras = setInterval(timer, 1000);
```

Comment: para que nunca el tiempo de promoción de un bloque nunca se venza, entonces la idea es que cuando llegue a 0 retome de nuevo los 30 min

Comment: verifica el código ahora, lo he adaptado a lo que tu necesitas